# Doubly Linked List Java Remove method does not work for any node besides head node

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

All of my methods work except for the remove method. Although it only works when the node to be removed is the head, it does not work for any other node to be removed after the head. After debugging for hours, I found out that the removing something other than the head only works when 'head' itself is referenced (not through storing the head value in a variable) such as head.next, head.next.next, etc. But statements such as curNode.next.prev = curNode.prev seem to not change the order of the list at all. Attached below is my entire doubly linked class as well as the node class, and a main method I use to check the code.

Doubly Linked Node Class

```
public class DLNode {
    Object data;
    DLNode next;
    DLNode prev;

    DLNode(Object o) {
        data = o;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + data + "]";
    }

}
```

Doubly Linked List Class

```
public class DLList {
    DLNode head;
    DLList(){
        head = null;
    }
    public void append(DLNode newNode) {
        if (head == null ) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            DLNode curNode = head;
            while (curNode.next != null) {
                curNode.prev = curNode;
                curNode = curNode.next;             
            }
            curNode.next = newNode;
            curNode.prev = newNode.prev;
        }

    }
    public void prepend(DLNode newNode) {
        if (head == null) {
            head.prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            newNode.prev = null;
        }
        else {
            DLNode n = head;
            head.prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            newNode.next = n;
            newNode.prev = null;

        }
    }
    public void insertAfter(DLNode curNode, DLNode newNode) {
        DLNode sucNode = head.next;
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            sucNode = curNode.next;
            newNode.next = sucNode;
            newNode.prev = curNode;
            curNode.next = newNode;
            sucNode.prev = newNode;
        }

    }
    public void remove(DLNode curNode) {
        DLNode sucNode = curNode.next; //these variables don't seem to work without
        DLNode predNode = curNode.prev; //the head node directly referenced
        if (head == null) {
            curNode = null;
        }
        else if (curNode == head) { //only block that works
            head = sucNode;
        }
        else if (sucNode != null) {
            sucNode.prev = predNode; //where the problem is apparently
        }
        else if (predNode != null) {
            predNode.next = sucNode;
        }

    }
    public DLNode search(Object key) {
        DLNode curNode = head;
        while (curNode != null) {
            if (curNode.data == key) {
                return curNode;
            }
            curNode = curNode.next;
        }
        return curNode;
    }

    public void insertAfterNew(DLNode curNode, DLNode newNode) {
        DLNode sucNode = head.next;
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else if (curNode == null) {
            newNode.next = sucNode;
            head = newNode;
            sucNode.prev = newNode;
        }
        else {
            sucNode = curNode.next;
            newNode.next = sucNode;
            newNode.prev = curNode;
            curNode.next = newNode;
            sucNode.prev = newNode;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String finalString = "X<-";
        DLNode curNode = head;
        if (head == null) {
            return "X";
        }
        while (curNode != null) {
            if (curNode.next == null) {
                finalString += curNode;
                curNode = curNode.next;
            }
            else {  
                finalString += curNode + "<=>";
                curNode = curNode.next;
            }
        }
        return finalString + "->X";
    }
    }
```

Test Class with main

```
public class TestList {
    static final int N = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testDLList();
    }

    static void testDLList() {

        System.out.println("Doubly-Linked List");

        DLList list2 = new DLList();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            list2.append(new DLNode(i));
        for (double d = N; d < 2 * N; d++)
            list2.append(new DLNode(d));

        System.out.println(list2);

        DLNode temp = list2.search(1); //remove works when the value in search is 0
        System.out.println(temp); // since 0 is head, but not with other values in list

        list2.insertAfter(temp, new DLNode(2000));
        System.out.println(list2);

        list2.remove(temp);
        System.out.println(list2);

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: If you have a doubly linked list, shouldn't there be two references that need to be updated? If you have nodes `A <-> B <-> C` and you remove node `B`, you need to set `A.next = C` and `C.prev = A`, no? Your `remove()` method consists entirely of `else if` blocks so at most only one reference will be updated, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I tried using both A.next(predNode.next) and C.prev(sucNode.prev) in the same block as well and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply [user7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48733181/444402) together with the suggestions I made in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733011/doubly-linked-list-java-remove-method-does-not-work-for-any-node-besides-head-no/48739297#comment84465348_48733011).

```
public void append(DLNode newNode) {
    if (head == null ) {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        DLNode curNode = head;
        while (curNode.next != null)
            curNode = curNode.next; 
        curNode.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = curNode;
    }

}

public void remove(DLNode curNode) {
    DLNode sucNode = curNode.next;
    DLNode predNode = curNode.prev;
    if (sucNode != null)
        sucNode.prev = predNode;
    if (predNode != null)
        predNode.next = sucNode;
    else if (curNode == head)
        head = sucNode;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

}
```

See user7's answer for the explanation on the changes to `append()`. As for `remove()`, there are four scenarios:

- If the list looks like `predNode <-> curNode <-> sucNode`, i.e. `predNode != null && sucNode != null`, you need to set `sucNode.prev = predNode` and `predNode.next = sucNode`
- If the list looks like `predNode <-> curNode`, i.e. `predNode != null && sucNode == null`, you need to set `predNode.next = null`
- If the list looks like `curNode <-> sucNode`, i.e. `predNode == null && sucNode != null`, you need to set `sucNode.prev = null` and `head = sucNode`
- If the list looks like `curNode`, i.e. `predNode == null && sucNode == null`, you need to set `head = null`

The fixed `remove()` method handles these four cases correctly and also sanity checks that `curNode == head` when `predNode == null`.

---

Your `insertAfter()` is also broken. For one thing, the `head == null` check is useless because `head.next` will always throw a NullPointerException before the `head == null` check is reached. I'm not quite sure I follow the intended logic, but here's a fixed version and an explanation:

```
public void insertAfter(DLNode curNode, DLNode newNode) {
    DLNode sucNode;

    if (curNode == null) {
        sucNode = head;
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        sucNode = curNode.next;
        curNode.next = newNode;
    }
    newNode.prev = curNode;

    newNode.next = sucNode;
    if (sucNode != null)
        sucNode.prev = newNode;
}
```

- If the list is empty, i.e. `curNode == null && head == null`, you need to set `newNode.prev = null`, `newNode.next = null`, and `head = newNode`
- If `newNode` should be inserted at the head of the list, i.e. `curNode == null && head != null`, you need to set `newNode.prev = null`, `newNode.next = head`, and `head = newNode`
- If `newNode` is being appended to the tail of the list, i.e. `curNode != null && curNode.next == null`, you need to set `newNode.prev = curNode`, `newNode.next = null`, and `curNode.next = newNode`
- If `newNode` is being inserted between two nodes, i.e. `curNode != null && curNode.next != null`, you need to set `newNode.prev = curNode`, `newNode.next = curNode.next`, and `curNode.next = newNode`

---

Your `prepend()` is also broken since `head.prev` will always throw a NullPointerException in the `head == null` branch. The `head != null` branch works correctly but uses an unnecessary temporary variable. Here's a fixed version:

```
public void prepend(DLNode newNode) {
    if (head == null) {
        newNode.next = null;
        head = newNode;
        newNode.prev = null;
    } else {
        head.prev = newNode;
        newNode.next = head;
        newNode.prev = null;
        head = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I really appreciate you putting all this work into the code and for the well thought-out explanations! I didn't think that the problem was outside of the remove method, but turns out it was all over the place lol. Your answer really helped me to understand what went wrong and gave me confidence that there are people out there willing to help since this is the first question i've ever posted on stack! Thank you very much and everything works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `append`. I have commented the lines to be removed with the reason and also added few ones.

```
public void append(DLNode newNode) {
    if (head == null ) {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        DLNode curNode = head;
        while (curNode.next != null) {
           // curNode.prev = curNode; Shouldn't be updating the prev when traversing
            curNode = curNode.next;     //Traverse         
        }
        curNode.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = curNode;
        //curNode.prev = newNode.prev; This also must be removed. This cuts off the nodes from the list
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply! Unfortunately this did not work for me. It still returns X<-[0]<=>[1]<=>[2000]<=>[2]<=>[3]<=>[4.0]<=>[5.0]<=>[6.0]<=>[7.0]->X for me without removing [1].